# Golang - Type decimal.Decimal convert

Tags: go, type-conversion, decimal

Trying to convert type decimal.Decimal to string

```
func main() {
    a := strconv.Itoa(Price) // Price of type decimal.Decimal
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", a)
}
```

Problem: cannot use (variable of type decimal.Decimal) as int value in argument to strconv.Itoa (compile)go-staticcheck

Example code that works will be apreciated

Comment: There's a bunch of decimal packages available (it's not part of the go standard library).  Which one did you use?  See https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=decimal&m=

Answer (score 4):

Price is `decimal.Decimal` not int. `strconv.Itoa` accepts int.

From docs https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/shopspring/decimal#Decimal.String
use `.String()`.

Comment: Thank you Lucas Katayama. Your feedback helped me with this issue.